# Linux mint boot fails.CPU not responding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, linux-mint

My Linuxmint system fails to boot when i restarted my system after some software installations,specifically nginx,passenger,ruby,rails and mongodb.
I did'nt remember whether i have removed any system dependencies while installation.

Now on booting message shows like

```
smpboot: CPU1: Not responding
smpboot: do_boot_cpu failed(-1) to wakeup CPU1
smpboot: CPU2: Not responding
smpboot: do_boot_cpu failed(-1) to wakeup CPU2
```

and system then turns to power save mode.

I used purge command for removing old versions of nginx and mongodb.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your software installations probably included a kernel upgrade.

Comment: Is there any solution to fix that?only grub command line is available from message screen.

Comment: Or any way to undo kernal upgrade

Comment: Installations happened quickly,if kernel upgradation happened it would have taken some more time.So i think it is more about some important dependencies being removed.

Comment: Upgrading the kernel just means replacing some files. It’s very fast. At this point in the boot process, there is nothing but the kernel.

Comment: If so is there any option to check/undo upgraded files?